# ionic cordova build android error nuillpoijtexception

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I run `cordova build android` I had error.

```
exit /b 1 Command finished with error code 1:\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,myprodplatforms\android\build.gradle myprodplatforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at 
org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63) Error: myprodplatforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (myprodnode_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (myprodnode_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**I tried to remove and add android remove node modules**, **I updated node module to latest version .**

Can someone give me idea how to solved error.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, One thing seems typo, the command is `ionic cordova build android`, you have mentioned only `cordova build android` command, `ionic` is missing.

It seems your error is more related to Android Studio/Gradle installation not related to node module or ionic. still as per error mentioned which itself suggests please run build command with --verbose flag as below.

> `ionic cordova build android --verbose`

the `--verbose` flag may help you to give exact Gradle or specific component associated error, which can further help you to reach to the specific root cause.

Comment: thank you for your answare, I instaled android stuido and have Gradble, and after try command 

ionic cordova build android --verbose

I had error what in in my questios.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `ionic cordova build android` instead of `cordova build android` to get APK and run `ionic cordova build ios` to get IPA